# How to start an activity which is in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I want to start auto reject list with intent. Like this code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("WHICH SHOULD I WRITE CODE IN HERE?");
            startActivity(intent);
```

How can I this?

Comment: What is "auto reject list"?

Comment: @CommonsWare https://affordablegifts4both.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/2.png

Comment: That is not part of Android. If that is a third-party app, ask its developer how to launch it. If that is part of some device firmware, ask the device manufacturer how to launch it.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, activityYouWantToStart);` is what you're looking for, ***however*** as @CommonsWare said, it is not a part of Android, so it will not work for your particular issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare  That is a setting to block calls on an Android.

Comment: If you can find it's package then simply fire an intent to open that package. Put it in try catch though.

Comment: @Tushar Which should I write code in catch?

Comment: "That is a setting to block calls on an Android" -- on your device, perhaps. It is not part of standard Android.

Comment: Something like this::: `Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}`

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe, but how is blocked calls on standart Android?

Comment: There is no feature to block calls in standard Android.

Answer (score 0):

If the first activity is MainActivity and the second activity is SecondActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```